# Jar not being found when running tomcat war in Docker

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, servlets, gurobi

I've made a war to run on my tomcat server in a Docker container. The servlet runs fine in eclipse, but when I have compiled it put it in my Docker it isn't loading in the required classes properly.

[Project structure and manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7TFr.png)

When I try and access the servlet using my browser I get this error.

[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzPzO.png)

I went into the Docker container and checked that gurobi.jar is still in WEB-INF/lib/ and it is.

I don't know why this wouldn't be able to find the jar, as it works fine when it's in Eclipse.

docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'projectdb'
       MYSQL_USER: ''
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
     - ./GurServ.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/GurServ.war
  java:
    image: bitnami/java:latest
    volumes:
     - .:/app
     - .:/code
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD exec gunicorn djangoapp.wsgi:application - bind 0.0.0.0:8000 - workers 3
```

Project structure

```
...
Java Resources
   src
      ... 
WebContent
   META-INF
      MANIFEST.MF
   WEB-INF
      gurobi-javadoc.jar
      gurobi.jar
```

Comment: Please add the content of your Dockerfile to your question (as text not an image). Please consider revising the question to include text descriptions of your project structure and the stacktrace to make it easier for others to review this.

Comment: Your container image configuration is incorrect:`NoClassDefFoundError` and the jar (or a dependency) is not correctly configured: `GRBEnv.java` (#43) is throwing the exception `Cound not initialize class gurobi.GurobiJni`

Comment: And: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025357212-How-to-handle-a-NoClassDefFoundError-

Comment: I've added docker-compose and Dockerfile. I've looked at that link before, but I've set the classpath in the manifest file, or does it need to go somewhere in docker as well?

Comment: Thanks for adding the files. I'm unfamiliar with Gurobi and don't have the JAR so I can't help. Hopefully others can. The evidence suggests that Tomcat's unable either to find `gurobi.jar` or some dependency of it. The fact that it references JNI is relevant too. It may be that it's not the JAR that's at fault but a native (shared library).

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'm not sure why it can't find it in Docker but it can in Eclipse

Comment: One of the benefits of Docker is exactly this issue.... differences between environments without Docker ;-) Is Eclipse using Tomcat or some other servlet engine? It's possible, if it's using Tomcat that the issue is with a shared library dependency that exists on your host but is not available within the container.